# Optimization of python multithreading script - huge memory consumption

Tags: python, multithreading, memory

I have a script (Django Management-Command) wiht over 800 lines of code.
This should import data from a external Web-Service, manipulate sth. and write it to a Postgres DB.

I use multithreading, because fetching data from webservice ist not very fast.

There ist one Thread for fetching the data with a bulk command to get a bulk of 64 data sets an write each data set in a queue.

Simultaneously at the beginning there is one worker-thread wich manipulates the data and write it to a DB.
In the main (handle) class, there is a while-loop that looks every 5 seconds for the quantity of elements in the queue and the quantity of running worker-threads.
If there are more than 500 elements in the queue and there are less then 5 worker-threads, it starts a new worker-thread.

All worker-threads get one item from the queue, manipulate sth., write the data set to the DB and append one String (up to 14 chars) to a different queue (#2).

The queue #2 ist necessary to have all imported objects at the end of the import to mark them as new respectively delete all other items from the DB, which are currently not imported.

For DB's with a quantity of not more then 200.000 data sets everything works fine.
But if there is for example a DB with 1.000.000 data sets, the memory consumption increases during the processing of the hole script up to 8 GB of RAM.

Is there a method to watch the memory consumption of threads and / or queue's?
Is there a method to "clean" memory after each while-loop?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import threading
import Queue
import time

from optparse import OptionParser, make_option
from decimal import Decimal
from datetime import datetime

from django.core.management import call_command
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.conf import settings


def is_someone_alive(thread_list):
    so_alive = False
    for t in thread_list:
        if t.is_alive():
            so_alive = True
    return so_alive


class insert_item(threading.Thread):
    VarLock2 = threading.Lock()

    def __init__(self, queue1, item_still_exist2, name, *args, **options):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.options = options
        self.name = name
        self.queue1 = queue1
        self.item_still_exist2 = item_still_exist2

    def run(self):

        while not self.queue1.empty() or getItemBulkThread.isrunning:

            item = self.queue1.get()
            artikelobj, created = Artikel.objects.get_or_create(artikelnr=item['Nr'])

            """
            manipulate data
            """

            self.item_still_exist2.put(artikelobj.artikelnr)

            artikelobj.save()

            self.queue1.task_done()


class getItemBulkThread(threading.Thread):
    isrunning = True
    VarLock = threading.Lock()

    def __init__(self, queue1, name, *args, **options):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.options = options
        if self.options['nrStart'] != '':
            self.nrab = self.options['nrStart']
        else:
            self.nrab = ''
        self.name = name
        #self.nrab = '701307'
        self.queue1 = queue1
        self.anz_artikel = 64
        self.max_artikel = 64
        self.skipped = 0
        self.max_skip = 20

    def run(self):

        count_sleep = 0
        while True:

            while self.queue1.qsize() > 5000:
                time.sleep(5)
                count_sleep += 1

            if count_sleep > 0:
                print "~ Artikel-Import %(csleep)sx für 5s pausiert, da Queue-Size > 5000" % {'csleep': count_sleep}
                count_sleep = 0

            try:
                items = getItemBulk()  # from external service

            except Exception as exc1:
                if ('"normal" abort-condition' in str(exc1)):
                    getItemBulkThread.VarLock.acquire()
                    getItemBulkThread.isrunning = False
                    getItemBulkThread.VarLock.release()
                    break
                elif self.anz_artikel > 1:
                    self.anz_artikel /= 2
                    continue
                elif self.skipped <= self.max_skip:
                    self.nrab += 1
                    self.skipped += 1
                    time.sleep(5)
                    continue
                elif self.skipped > self.max_skip:
                    raise Exception("[EXCEPTION] Fehler im Thread: too much items skipped")
                else:
                    getItemBulkThread.VarLock.acquire()
                    getItemBulkThread.isrunning = False
                    getItemBulkThread.VarLock.release()
                    raise

            last_item = len(items) - 1
            self.nrab = items[last_item]['Nr']

            for artikel in items:
                artikel['katItem'] = False
                self.queue1.put(artikel)

            if self.anz_artikel < self.max_artikel:
                self.anz_artikel *= 2
                self.skipped = 0


class Command(BaseCommand):
    """
      Django-mgm-command
    """
    help = u'Import'

    def create_parser(self, prog_name, subcommand):
        """
        Create and return the ``OptionParser`` which will be used to
        parse the arguments to this command.
        """
        return OptionParser(prog=prog_name, usage=self.usage(subcommand),
            version=self.get_version(),
            option_list=self.option_list,
            conflict_handler="resolve")

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        startzeit = datetime.now()
        anzahl_Artikel_vorher = Artikel.objects.all().count()  # Artikel is a model

        self.options = options

        items_vorher = []

        queue1 = Queue.Queue()
        item_still_exists2 = Queue.Queue()

        running_threads = []

        thread = getItemBulkThread(queue1, name="Artikel", *args, **options)
        running_threads.append(thread)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

        anz_worker_threads = 1
        anz_max_worker_threads = 5

        insert_threads = [insert_item(queue1, item_still_exists2, name="Worker-%(anz)s" % {'anz': i + 1}, *args, **options) for i in range(anz_worker_threads)]
        for thread in insert_threads:
            running_threads.append(thread)
            thread.setDaemon(True)
            thread.start()

        add_seconds = 5
        element_grenze = 500
        lastelemente = 0
        asc_elemente = 0
        anz_abgearbeitet = 0

        while getItemBulkThread.isrunning or not queue1.empty():
            time.sleep(add_seconds)
            elemente = queue1.qsize()
            akt_zeit = datetime.now()
            diff_zeit = akt_zeit - startzeit
            diff = elemente - lastelemente
            anz_abgearbeitet = item_still_exists2.qsize()
            art_speed = (anz_abgearbeitet / timedelta_total_seconds(diff_zeit)) * 60
            ersetz_var = {'anz': elemente, 'zeit': diff_zeit, 'tstamp': akt_zeit.strftime('%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S'), 'anzw': anz_worker_threads, 'diff': diff, 'anza': anz_abgearbeitet, 'art_speed': art_speed}
            print("%(zeit)s vergangen - %(tstamp)s - %(anz)s Elemente in Queue, Veränderung: %(diff)s - Anz Worker: %(anzw)s - Artikel importiert: %(anza)s - Speed: %(art_speed)02d Art/Min" % ersetz_var)

            if diff > 0:
                asc_elemente += 1
            else:
                asc_elemente = 0
            if asc_elemente > 2 and anz_worker_threads < anz_max_worker_threads and elemente > element_grenze:
                ersetz_var = {'maxw': anz_max_worker_threads, 'nr': anz_worker_threads + 1, 'element_grenze': element_grenze}
                print "~~ 2x in Folge mehr Queue-Elemente als vorher, die max. Anzahl an Workern %(maxw)s noch nicht erreicht und mehr als %(element_grenze)s Elemente in der Queue, daher Start eines neuen Workers (Nr %(nr)s)" % ersetz_var
                anz_worker_threads += 1
                thread = insert_item(queue1, item_still_exists2, name="Worker-%(anz)s" % {'anz': anz_worker_threads}, *args, **options)
                running_threads.append(thread)
                thread.setDaemon(True)
                thread.start()
                asc_elemente = 0
            lastelemente = elemente

        queue1.join()

        items_nachher = []
        while not item_still_exists2.empty():
            item = item_still_exists2.get()
            if item in items_vorher:
                items_nachher.append(item)
                items_vorher.remove(item)
            item_still_exists2.task_done()

        item_still_exists2.join()

        if len(items_vorher) > 0:
            Artikel.objects.filter(artikelnr__in=items_vorher).delete()

        anzahl_Artikel_nachher = Artikel.objects.all().count()
        anzahl_Artikel_diff = anzahl_Artikel_nachher - anzahl_Artikel_vorher

        endzeit = datetime.now()
        dauer = endzeit - startzeit
```

I've abbreviated the Code at some positions :)

Comment: I have no experience with multithreading in Python but I read *a lot* that you shouldn't do it, because Python sucks in this regard. A better approach should be to use a multiprocessing framework like [zeromq](http://www.zeromq.org/) and pipe your tasks from your python process to your multiprocessing tooling.

Comment: Use for "fetching data from webservice" ioloop approach, i.e. with "green threads" (`gevent`, `eventlet` or something similar to this).

Comment: Does `Artikel.objects` perhaps keep your objects in memory?

Comment: I see a couple of places where something gets added to the `running_threads` list, but nothing ever seems to be removed...

Comment: @erikb85 actually it all depends on the situation. Python uses real OS threads and has no responsability for scheduling etc. which in some situations is good, while in others it is not.
Python has a built-in multiprocessing module that allows to create shared objects and/or queues/pipes between processes so you do not have to use external libraries.

Comment: @martineau: In this list are only the thread objects (max 6 (1 get and 5 worker)). Each must end on its own, otherwise the import is not ended.

Comment: @Janne Karila
Possible I've a understanding problem.

There is the while-loop:

    while not self.queue1.empty() or getItemBulkThread.isrunning:
        item = self.queue1.get()
        artikelobj, created = Artikel.objects.get_or_create(artikelnr=item['Nr'])

Does Python saves every obj in memory? I thought this schould be overwritten in the next loop-pass.

Answer (score 1):

A possible cause for excessive memory consumption is that you don't set a maximum size for the input queue. See [the `maxsize` parameter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue).

On a related note, you write:

> In the main (handle) class, there is a while-loop that looks every 5
>   seconds for the quantity of elements in the queue and the quantity of
>   running worker-threads. If there are more than 500 elements in the
>   queue and there are less then 5 worker-threads, it starts a new
>   worker-thread.

Creating a new thread does not necessarily increase the throughput. You should rather do some tests to determine the optimal number of threads, which may turn out to be 1.

Comment: There is a simple logic before a new thread was started (see code in post). 
thx for the hint with the maxsize, i'll try it. We tested out the maximum no of worker-threads that make sense.